# Extending storage with internal or external drive

Tags: ssd

I have a windows 10 desktop. I need to store about 800 GB of data for developing a trading application. I would be storing the data less frequently in it (most likely once) and then reading the data from it quite often. I was looking to get a solid state external drive USB 3.0 but not sure if that would make the reading of data very slow (would it be slower than reading from internal HDD). What do you recommend I should do?

Comment: Need a bit more info here. You say you will constantly be reading data, but what kind of data is it? What types of files? Just a database? What is the estimated throughput of your application?

Comment: "would it be slower than reading from internal HDD" Slower then an internal SSD, faster then a external HDD, about still slower then the internal HDD.

Comment: Data is quotes and trades of every stock in the US stock market. It will be stored in binary files and read from programs written in R and C++. Ramhound- thank you for your response. Can one have an internal HDD and internal SSD in a desktop Windows PC?

Answer (score 0):

Having in mind the purpose you wan to use the drive for I would suggest to go with an internal drive because the speed of an external might not be good enough, especially for the programs you've mentioned.

You can have both types of drives in your PC as long as you have the necessary interface to plug them in (SATA in most cases), or in other words, you need to have free ports on your motherboards. Actually, if you don't have enough you may consider a SATA multiplier, which will basically enable the use of multiple drives to a single SATA port, but limits all drives to the SATA speed (for example 4 drives on a 6Gb/s port will have 1.5Gb/s limit each). It looks similar to a RAID controller, but it differs from it as those controllers enable a full speed potential on each drive while the multiplier limits all drives to the single port's speed.

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using an internal HDD directly connected to a SATA bus (which is what you will find on most desktops) will always be faster than adding a extra step in between (E.g. USB to USB to SATA bridge to SATA disk).

Thus:

1. Internal HDD is faster than an external USB connected HDD drive.
2. Internal SSD is faster than an external USB connected SDD drive.

Internal also has the advantage of not having an extra 'box' connected to you tower. No need for an additonal power supply (which is needed for some external drives) and it often has better cooling.

The only reason I can find for an external drive is if you have to move it occasionally and want to do so without opening the desktop case. That is not the case described in your post so I would go for an internal solution.

And since HDD are quite good at sequantial read speeds I would consider a regular harddisk (aka rotating rust) since that still is the best economical solution. If money is no problem go for a regular SATA SSD or even for an M.2 NVME SSD.